# Node resize image and upload to AWS

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm relatively new to node, and want to write a module that takes an image from an S3 bucket, resizes it and saves it to a temporary directory on Amazon's new Lambda service and then uploads the images back to the bucket.

When I run the code, none of my functions seem to be called (`download`, `transform` and `upload`). I am using `tmp` to create the temporary directory and `graphicsMagick` to resize the image.

What is wrong with my code?

I have defined the dependencies and the array outside of the module, because I have another which depends on these.

```
// dependencies
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var gm = require('gm').subClass({ imageMagick: true });
var fs = require("fs");
var tmp = require("tmp");

// get reference to S3 client
var s3 = new AWS.S3();

var _800px = {
    width: 800,
    destinationPath: "large"
};

var _500px = {
    width: 500,
    destinationPath: "medium"
};

var _200px = {
    width: 200,
    destinationPath: "small"
};

var _45px = {
    width: 45,
    destinationPath: "thumbnail"
};

var _sizesArray = [_800px, _500px, _200px, _45px];

var len = _sizesArray.length;

exports.AwsHandler = function(event) {
    // Read options from the event.
    var srcBucket = event.Records[0].s3.bucket.name;
    var srcKey = event.Records[0].s3.object.key;
    var dstnKey = srcKey;

    // create temporary directory
    var tmpobj = tmp.dirSync();

    // function to determine paths
    function _filePath (directory, i) {
        if (!directory) {
            return "dst/" + _sizesArray[i].destinationPath + "/" + dstnKey;
        } else {
            return directory + "/dst/" + _sizesArray[i].destinationPath + "/" + dstnKey;
        }
    };


    // Infer the image type.
    var typeMatch = srcKey.match(/\.([^.]*)$/);
    if (!typeMatch) {
        console.error('unable to infer image type for key ' + srcKey);
        return;
    };

    var imageType = typeMatch[1];

    if (imageType != "jpg" && imageType != "png") {
        console.log('skipping non-image ' + srcKey);
        return;
    };


    (function resizeImage () {
        function download () {

            console.log("started!");

            s3.getObject({
                    Bucket: srcBucket,
                    Key: srcKey
                },
                function (err, response) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.error(err);
                    }
                    // call transform if successful
                    transform (response);
                }
            );
        };

        function transform (response) {

            for ( var i = 0; i<len; i++ ) {

                // define path for image write
                var _Key = _filePath (tmpobj, i);

                // resize images
                gm(response.Body, srcKey)
                    .resize(_sizesArray[i].width)
                    .write(_Key, function (err) {
                        if (err) {
                            console.error(err);
                        }
                        upLoad ();
                    });
            }
        };

        function upLoad () {

            for ( var i = 0; i<len; i++ ) {

                var readPath = _filePath (tmpobj, i);

                var writePath = _filePath (i);

                // read file from temp directory
                fs.readFile(readPath, function (err, data) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.error(err);
                    }

                    // upload images to s3 bucket
                    s3.putObject({
                        Bucket: srcBucket,
                        Key: writePath,
                        Body: data,
                        ContentType: data.type
                    },
                    function (err) {
                        if (err) {
                            console.error(err);
                        }
                        console.log("Uploaded with success!");
                    });
                })
            }
            // Manual cleanup of temporary directory
            tmpobj.removeCallback();
        };
    }());
};
```

Comment: You never called `download()`

Comment: I was under the impression that Lambda would call it. However I have just discovered that i need to configure which function it must call. Does this mean that my node code is written correctly then?

Comment: It's a little complex, and you could make it much cleaner, but I don't notice anything obviously wrong. The lambda will run but all it does is define three functions internally: download, transform, upLoad. then it calls tmpObj.removeCallback().

Comment: Looking more closely you are going to run into an issue: you loop through sizes, call gm() once for each size, and call upLoad() in the callback from gm. So the upLoad callback will be called four times whenever gm gets done. And the other formatted gm output files might not be available.

Comment: What if I call `upLoad` outside of the for loop? Wouldn't that mitigate that problem?

Comment: I removed `upLoad` from the for loop and now get the following error :
`enonent open`, meaning the file/directory does not exist. Doesn't Lambda's /tmp directory work like a normal directory? What's going on?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a partial improvement, note the use of the [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) library. You will have issues in upLoad() because you are firing four asynchronous calls immediately (in the for loop) and there's no easy way to know when they are all done. (well, the easy way is to rewrite the function to use the async library, like async.forEach)

```
// dependencies
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var gm = require('gm').subClass({ imageMagick: true });
var fs = require("fs");
var tmp = require("tmp");
var async = require("async");

// get reference to S3 client
var s3 = new AWS.S3();

var _800px = {
  width: 800,
  destinationPath: "large"
};

var _500px = {
  width: 500,
  destinationPath: "medium"
};

var _200px = {
  width: 200,
  destinationPath: "small"
};

var _45px = {
  width: 45,
  destinationPath: "thumbnail"
};

var _sizesArray = [_800px, _500px, _200px, _45px];

var len = _sizesArray.length;

exports.AwsHandler = function(event) {
  // Read options from the event.
  var srcBucket = event.Records[0].s3.bucket.name;
  var srcKey = event.Records[0].s3.object.key;
  var dstnKey = srcKey;

  // create temporary directory
  var tmpobj = tmp.dirSync();

  // function to determine paths
  function _filePath (directory, i) {
    if (!directory) {
      return "dst/" + _sizesArray[i].destinationPath + "/" + dstnKey;
    } else {
      return directory + "/dst/" + _sizesArray[i].destinationPath + "/" + dstnKey;
    }
  };


  // Infer the image type.
  var typeMatch = srcKey.match(/\.([^.]*)$/);
  if (!typeMatch) {
    console.error('unable to infer image type for key ' + srcKey);
    return;
  };

  var imageType = typeMatch[1];

  if (imageType != "jpg" && imageType != "png") {
    console.log('skipping non-image ' + srcKey);
    return;
  };


  // Actually call resizeImage, the main pipeline function:
  resizeImage(function(err){
    // Done. Manual cleanup of temporary directory
    tmpobj.removeCallback();
  })


  function resizeImage (callback) {
    var s3obj = {
      Bucket: srcBucket,
      Key: srcKey
    };
    download(s3obj, function(response){
      var gmConfigs = sizesArray.map(function(size, i){
        return {
          width: size.width
          _Key: _filePath (tmpobj, i)
        }
      })

      async.eachSeries(gmConfigs,
      function(config, done){
        transform(response, config.width, config._Key, done)
      },
      function(err){
        if(err){
          console.log(err);
        } else {
          upLoad();
          // Further work is required to identify if all the uploads worked,
          // and to know when to call callback() here
          // callback();
        }
      })
    })
  }

  function download (s3obj, callback) {
    console.log("started!");

    s3.getObject(s3obj, function (err, response) {
      if (err) {
        console.error(err);
      }
      // call transform if successful
      callback(response);
    });
  };

  function transform (response, width, _Key, callback) {
    // resize images
    gm(response.Body, srcKey)
    .resize(width)
    .write(_Key, function (err) {
      if (err) {
        console.error(err);
      }
      callback();
    });
  };

  function upLoad () {
    for ( var i = 0; i<len; i++ ) {
      var readPath = _filePath (tmpobj, i);
      var writePath = _filePath (i);
      // read file from temp directory
      fs.readFile(readPath, function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
          console.error(err);
        }

        // upload images to s3 bucket
        s3.putObject({
          Bucket: srcBucket,
          Key: writePath,
          Body: data,
          ContentType: data.type
        },
        function (err) {
          if (err) {
            console.error(err);
          }
          console.log("Uploaded with success!");
        });
      })
    }
  };

};
```